# Xcode Best way to search array or dictionary?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have some data that I need searched there are 401 entries like this:

"1","1","1","1","0",**"1"**

"1","2","1","1","0",**"2"**

"1","3","1","1","0",**"3"**

"1","1","2","1","0",**"1"**

....

"3","3","3","3","0",**"1"**

What I need is the best way to search the first 5 strings and then use the last string to fill a variable.

I am not sure how to do this, in .net I would use a datatable and just search that and get the data I need I am just not sure how to do it in Objective-C.

**Edit**

Its not homework, So I have a list of 401 rows in a SQL database so that have 6 columns the first 5 columns have results data the user selects a number from 1-3 lets say the last column is the data I am looking for so in SQL I would do something like:

Select Column6 from table where Column1 = 1 AND Column2 = 1 AND Column3 = 2 AND Column4 = 2 AND Column5 = 5

I dont know how to do this in objective-c the customer does not want me using any kind of network so they want a stand alone app. So I need to make a dictionary or array or txt file be able to search each row to match the 5 variables I have captured and then grab the 6th "Column" as the data.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the result you desire? Do you want to construct a new array by taking elements in steps of five from the original one?

Comment: I have a list of these 401 entries and need to search them I guess I am looking for the best method of doing this I am .net programmer and not that familiar with objective-c I know I can make a array or dictionary I just don't know the best way to A:what to use and B: once I have that way what is the best way to search it. The answer could be use a txt file I just don't know sorry. Like I stated I would use a datatable and search that if it was .net

Comment: you want to search in the source code in the Xcode or you want to search in the arrays programatically? because your question is not exactly clear.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have 5 results lets call them, I want to search the array, dictionary, txt file etc... so that the 5 results are equal to one of the 401 lines so I would search each row and see if they match the 5 results if they do then I would take the last string as the variable needed. I hope that makes since.

Comment: Your question still isn't quite clear; also, is this homework? If it is it's fine - just tag it appropriately. I would suggest you read over your question and EDIT it to include enough information for anyone reading it to figure out what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can manipulate the data, I would set this up as an `NSDictionary` or `NSMutableDictionary` with strings like `@"11110"` as the keys and strings like `@"1"` as the values. You can then just use `objectForKey:` to find the value you're looking for and set a variable with, say, `int myVariable = [string intValue]`.

To create a key out of the separate values, you could use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%i%i%i%i", column1, column2, column3, column4, column5]`.

Comment: I like this I am going to try it. 
Thank you!